# NSTimer won't Invalidate Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

Im not sure why my timer will not invalidate.

```
var timer = NSTimer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "loadCurrentGame", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.timer.invalidate()
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    self.timer.invalidate()
}
```

As you can see I tried calling invalidate from both viewWillDisappear as well as prepareForSegue. I imagine that this might have something to do with the timer being started on a different thread than I am attempting to invalidate it on.

I only want to timer to run while that view is active not when I'm on a different view.

It turns out due to a previous attempt at doing something I was calling viewDidLoad from ViewWillAppear(Which I now know is a bad practice), which caused this error.

Comment: "I imagine that this might have something to do with the timer being started on a different thread than I am attempting to invalidate it on.": It doesn't, both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillDisappear` are called on main thread.

Comment: Thanks, is prepareForSegue called on the main thread as well?

Comment: Yes, UIKit operates on main thread by default, unless clearly stated otherwise.

Comment: If you are mucking around with background threads then that would indeed cause a problem. However, you have to go out of your way to write code that runs in the background. Are you using GCD calls like dispatch_async, NSThreads, NSOperations, or the like?

Comment: Yea the function that fires from the timer does a NSURLSession that does an async request to my database, and then I dispatch_async for the main thread to sync the view labels/images with the database information.

Comment: So perhaps your timer is invalidated, but you already have a `loadCurrentGame` in flight when you switch view controllers.

Comment: Yea if it was just an extra one I wouldn't think its the end of the world at this point but it does continue forever at the 5 second interval.